# terraform resource creation - this keyword

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, infrastructure-as-code, hcl

I came across a pattern in couple of `terraform` code in Github.

```
resource "aws_vpc" "this"
```

I wanted to know how keyword `this` provides a particular advantage over a named resource. I can't find a **Hashicorp** documentation on `this` keyword.

https://github.com/terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-vpc/blob/3210728ee26665fab6b1f07417bcb0e518573a1d/main.tf

https://github.com/cloudposse/terraform-aws-vpn-connection/blob/master/context.tf

Comment: It's just a resource name. Not a very good or descriptive name... You can change it to whatever describes the VPC resource better in your environment. Also, you cannot have two "aws_vpc" resources with same name in same workspace

Answer (score 17, accepted):

No, there is **nothing special** about `this` in terms of TF syntax or handling. Its just a name that may indicate that you have only one VPC in your setup. But this is not enforced by TF mechanism. Other common names are `main` or just `vpc`.

Comment: What @Marcin said.  I just wanted to add, to whoever will see this in the future, please don't use the word "this" in Terraform.  It's lazy and makes your code less clear to those who will see it in the future.  Name your variables properly regardless of what language you're using.

Comment: Since the type of resource is already implied when anyone accesses a singleton resource (aws_vpc.this), `this` is reasonable in this special case. Not sure whats a good name when there is only instance of that thing in your app.

Comment: `this` is also encouraged by https://www.terraform-best-practices.com/naming - however, personally, I find `this` too noisy, and prefer `_` e.g. `resource "aws_vpc" "_"`.