# Reference several aws_iam_policy_document data sources created with for_each in Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, lambda, terraform, amazon-iam, terraform-provider-aws

I want to create multiple `aws_iam_policy_document` resources with `for_each`, to be later assumed by several roles, as follows:

```
# Policy to allow services to assume the role
data "aws_iam_policy_document" "this" {
  for_each           = var.lambda_configuration
  statement {
    actions = ["sts:AssumeRole"]

    principals {
      type = "Service"

      identifiers = [
        "lambda.amazonaws.com",
        "apigateway.amazonaws.com",
      ]
    }
  }
}

# IAM role for executing the Lambda function
resource "aws_iam_role" "this" {
  for_each           = var.lambda_configuration
  name               = "my_lambda_${each.key}_Executor_Role"
  description        = "Role for executing my_lambda-${each.key} function"
  assume_role_policy = data.aws_iam_policy_document.assume_role_policy_[each.key].json
}
```

How should I interpolate this

```
assume_role_policy = data.aws_iam_policy_document.assume_role_policy_[each.key].json
```

to make the correct matching with the roles?

Comment: Is it the same role policy as the one you defined as `this`?

Comment: Yes that's the one

Comment: Well, then you need only `assume_role_policy = data.aws_iam_policy_document.this[each.key].json`, I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct syntax:

```
data.aws_iam_policy_document.this[each.key].json
```

Note that this is not interpolation, as you mentioned in your question. It is just a value lookup. And I have no idea where you got `assume_role_policy_` from, but that is not valid HCL syntax.

Comment: Thanks, that was a typo actually

Answer (score 1):

This seems like a good situation for [Chaining `for_each` Between Resources](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/meta-arguments/for_each#chaining-for_each-between-resources), which (subjectively) tends to lead to a configuration where it's easier for an unfamiliar reader to follow the way data is flowing between the resources.

```
data "aws_iam_policy_document" "this" {
  for_each = var.lambda_configuration

  statement {
    actions = ["sts:AssumeRole"]

    principals {
      type = "Service"

      identifiers = [
        "lambda.amazonaws.com",
        "apigateway.amazonaws.com",
      ]
    }
  }
}

# IAM role for executing the Lambda function
resource "aws_iam_role" "this" {
  for_each = data.aws_iam_policy_document.this

  name               = "my_lambda_${each.key}_Executor_Role"
  description        = "Role for executing my_lambda-${each.key} function"
  assume_role_policy = each.value.json
}
```

Using the first resource itself as the `for_each` for the second one means that the two will always have exactly the same keys (because a resource with `for_each` appears in expressions as a map of objects using the keys from the `for_each` map), and that `each.value` inside the second block refers to the corresponding instance of the first block.

This has essentially the same behavior as using the index operator to select an element from `data.aws_iam_policy_document.this` using `each.key`, but  makes the relationship between these two resources a little more direct and so (again, subjectively) easier to read and maintain in future.

Comment: Very clear explanation, thanks. I initially confused the "this" reference from the original question to the "this" keyword from some of the programming language constructs. But looks like it can be any name as explained here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69126254/terraform-resource-creation-this-keyword